# Server side meteor this.userprofile

Tags: meteor, admin, document

I have the following code that renders the currentUsers' documents in a collection. However I want an admin belonging to the same organization to also be able to view and edit the collection. this.user.profile.organization does not work unfortunately. So, how would I allow the object to be available to admins from belonging to the same organization. EVery document that gets created gets the organization of the currentuser.

```
Meteor.publish('skills', function skillsPublication() {
    return Skills.find({
        owner: this.userId,
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're on the server, you can always query the user document from the MongoDB database.

```
Meteor.publish('skills', function skillsPublication() {
  const user = Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: this.userId })
  // now you can do user.profile.organization

  return Skills.find({
    $or: [
      { owner: this.userId },
      { organization: user.profile.organization }
    ] // returns a document owned by the user or owned by the user's organization
  })
})
```

Just a note, Meteor advises against using `.profile` field on your users collection, because that field is always published to the client. Meteor suggests that you use top-level keys on your user document instead.

For more info, read: https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#dont-use-profile